# Develop integral

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

What should I do if I want to develop integral $\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^n}{(x+t)^{2n+4}} dt$ to $\int \frac{x^{p-1}}{1+qx)^{p+r}}=\frac{\Gamma(p)\Gamma(r)}{q^p\Gamma(p+r)}$.

I write $\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^n}{x^{2n+4}(1-\frac{1}{x}t)^{2n+4}}dt$.
But I don't see this form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u = t/x$. Then

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{t^n}{(x + t)^{2n+4}}\, dt = \int_0^\infty \frac{(ux)^n}{(x + xu)^{2n+4}} x\, du = \frac{1}{x^{n+3}}\int_0^\infty \frac{u^{(n+1)-1}}{(1 + u)^{(n+1) + (n+3)}}\, du=\,...$$